Переменные уходят в бесконечность при первом запуске цикла while c#
Если запустить код приведённый ниже, то первая игра приведет нас к счёту 0:0 потому что переменные xx и yy почему-то уходят в бесконечность. Как это, и почему? Также есть вопросик, как можно добавлять картинки на окно, с помощью C#. И если кому не лень подскажите, можно ли эту "Войну и мир" как-то сократить? Заранее спасибо:)
P.S. Появилась ещё одна проблема, если выиграть сначала за X, а потом за Y очки засчитают X, а следующее очко засчитают Y. Также действует, если начать играть и за Y.
Есть следующий код на C#:
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace XorO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WinOrDefeat();
        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        int three = 0;
        int four = 0;
        int five = 0;
        int six = 0;
        int seven = 0;
        int eight = 0;
        int nine = 0;
        int win = 0;
        int xx = 0;
        int yy = 0;
        int WOD = 0;
        private void Return()
        {
            while (WOD == 1)
            {
                GameGrid.Children.Clear();
                X1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                X2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                X3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                X4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                X5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                X6.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                X7.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                X8.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                X9.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X1);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X2);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X3);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X4);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X5);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X6);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X7);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X8);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X9);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(X);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(O);
                X.Content = $"X: {xx}";
                O.Content = $"O: {yy}";
                WOD = 0;
                MessageBox.Show($"{xx}{yy}");
                x = 0; y = 0; one = 0; two = 0; three = 0; four = 0; five = 0; six = 0; seven = 0; eight = 0; nine = 0;
            }
        }
        private void X1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock ST = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.Black,

            };
            if (x == 0)
            {
                X1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(ST);
                ST.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(ST, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(ST, 1);
                one = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (y < x)
            {
                X1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(ST);
                ST.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(ST, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(ST, 1);
                one = 2;
                y++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (x == y)
            {
                X1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(ST);
                ST.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(ST, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(ST, 1);
                one = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            WinOrDefeat();
            win = 0;
        }

        private void X2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock STD = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.Black,

            };
            if (x == 0)
            {
                X2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STD);
                STD.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STD, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(STD, 1);
                two = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (y < x)
            {
                X2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STD);
                STD.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STD, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(STD, 1);
                two = 2;
                y++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (x == y)
            {
                X2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STD);
                STD.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STD, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(STD, 1);
                two = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            WinOrDefeat();
            win = 0;
        }

        private void X3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock STO = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.Black,

            };
            if (x == 0)
            {
                X3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STO);
                STO.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STO, 3);
                Grid.SetRow(STO, 1);
                three = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (y < x)
            {
                X3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STO);
                STO.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STO, 3);
                Grid.SetRow(STO, 1);
                three = 2;
                y++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (x == y)
            {
                X3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STO);
                STO.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STO, 3);
                Grid.SetRow(STO, 1);
                three = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            WinOrDefeat();
            win = 0;
        }

        private void X4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock STT = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.Black,

            };
            if (x == 0)
            {
                X4.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STT);
                STT.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STT, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(STT, 2);
                four = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (y < x)
            {
                X4.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STT);
                STT.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STT, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(STT, 2);
                four = 2;
                y++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (x == y)
            {
                X4.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STT);
                STT.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STT, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(STT, 2);
                four = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            WinOrDefeat();
            win = 0;
        }

        private void X5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock STDT = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.Black,

            };
            if (x == 0)
            {
                X5.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STDT);
                STDT.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STDT, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(STDT, 2);
                five = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (y < x)
            {
                X5.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STDT);
                STDT.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STDT, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(STDT, 2);
                five = 2;
                y++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (x == y)
            {
                X5.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STDT);
                STDT.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STDT, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(STDT, 2);
                five = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            WinOrDefeat();
            win = 0;
        }

        private void X6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock STF = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.Black,

            };
            if (x == 0)
            {
                X6.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STF);
                STF.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STF, 3);
                Grid.SetRow(STF, 2);
                six = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (y < x)
            {
                X6.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STF);
                STF.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STF, 3);
                Grid.SetRow(STF, 2);
                six = 2;
                y++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (x == y)
            {
                X6.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STF);
                STF.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STF, 3);
                Grid.SetRow(STF, 2);
                six = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            WinOrDefeat();
            win = 0;
        }

        private void X7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock STDF = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.Black,

            };
            if (x == 0)
            {
                X7.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STDF);
                STDF.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STDF, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(STDF, 3);
                seven = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (y < x)
            {
                X7.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STDF);
                STDF.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STDF, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(STDF, 3);
                seven = 2;
                y++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (x == y)
            {
                X7.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STDF);
                STDF.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STDF, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(STDF, 3);
                seven = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            WinOrDefeat();
            win = 0;
        }

        private void X8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock STS = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.Black,

            };
            if (x == 0)
            {
                X8.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STS);
                STS.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STS, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(STS, 3);
                eight = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (y < x)
            {
                X8.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STS);
                STS.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STS, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(STS, 3);
                eight = 2;
                y++;
                win = 1;
            }
            else if (x == y)
            {
                X8.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STS);
                STS.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STS, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(STS, 3);
                eight = 1;
                x++;
                win = 1;
            }
            WinOrDefeat();
            win = 0;
        }

        private void X9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock STDS = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.Black,

            };
            if (x == 0)
            {
                X9.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STDS);
                STDS.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STDS, 3);
                Grid.SetRow(STDS, 3);
                nine = 1;
                x++;
                WinOrDefeat();
                win = 0;
            }
            else if (y < x)
            {
                X9.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STDS);
                STDS.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STDS, 3);
                Grid.SetRow(STDS, 3);
                nine = 2;
                y++;
                WinOrDefeat();
                win = 0;
            }
            else if (x == y)
            {
                X9.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                GameGrid.Children.Add(STDS);
                STDS.Background = Brushes.Black;
                Grid.SetColumn(STDS, 3);
                Grid.SetRow(STDS, 3);
                nine = 1;
                x++;
                WinOrDefeat();
                win = 0;
            }
            WinOrDefeat();
            win = 0;
        }
        private void WinOrDefeat()
        {
            while (win == 1)
            {
                if (one == 1 && two == 1 && three == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа X");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); xx+=1; win = 0; break;

                }
                else if (one == 2 && two == 2 && three == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа Y");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); yy+=1; break;

                }
                else if (three == 1 && six == 1 && nine == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа X");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); xx+=1; win = 0; break;

                }
                else if (three == 2 && six == 2 && nine == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа Y");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); yy+=1; break;

                }
                else if (seven == 1 && eight == 1 && nine == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа X");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); xx+=1; win = 0; break;

                }
                else if (seven == 2 && eight == 2 && nine == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа Y");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); yy+=1; break;

                }
                else if (one == 1 && four == 1 && seven == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа X");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); xx+=1; win = 0; break;

                }
                else if (one == 2 && four == 2 && seven == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа Y");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); yy+=1; break;

                }
                else if (four == 1 && five == 1 && six == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа X");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); xx+=1; win = 0; break;

                }
                else if (four == 2 && five == 2 && six == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа Y");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); yy+=1; break;

                }
                else if (two == 1 && five == 1 && eight == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа X");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); xx+=1; win = 0; break;

                }
                else if (two == 2 && five == 2 && eight == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа Y");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); yy+=1; break;

                }
                else if (one == 1 && five == 1 && nine == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа X");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); xx+=1; win = 0; break;

                }
                else if (one == 2 && five == 2 && nine == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа Y");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); yy+=1; break;

                }
                else if (three == 1 && five == 1 && seven == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа X");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); xx+=1; win = 0; break;

                }
                else if (three == 2 && five == 2 && seven == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Победа Y");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); yy+=1; break;

                }
                else if (one != 0 && two != 0 && three != 0 && four != 0 && five != 0 && six != 0 && seven != 0 && eight != 0 && nine != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ничья");
                    WOD = 1; Return(); xx+=1; yy+=1;; break;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

А вот ещё код на xaml:
<Window x:Class="XorO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XorO"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Grid x:Name="GameGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="X1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Click="X1_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="X2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Click="X2_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="X3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Click="X3_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="X4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Click="X4_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="X5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Click="X5_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="X6" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Click="X6_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="X7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Click="X7_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="X8" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Click="X8_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="X9" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Click="X9_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="X" Content="X: 0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="40"/>
        <Label x:Name="O" Content="O: 0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="40"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>



Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как правильно задавать вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

просто из любопытства - зачем здесь нужны циклы while ( оба два)?

@Uranus если бы ты не написал, я бы не заметил, что он реально не нужен. Я уже решил проблему с неправильным счетом, проблема в следующем: "Return(); xx+=1; yy+=1;", а надо просто было написать вот так: "xx+=1; yy+=1; Return();". Так же я понял как сократить код, но есть проблема с Textblock(будет заменен на что-то типа StackPanel), надо как-то туда добавлять картинки: "O.png" и "X.png", а также я выявил проблему с тем, что алгоритм вычисления победы какой-то очень большой.

Если вопрос устарел, удалите и создайте новый. Кстати, подсказка, попробуйте UniformGrid. В WPF не рекомендуется использовать Label, вместо него используют TextBlock. Кстати, вот простой пример как сделать интерфейс, изучите.

Есть в программировании такое правило Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) "Не повторяй себя". Оно означет, что если вам приходится писать повторяющийся код, вы делаете ошибку. Разбейте код на методы, он станет короче раз в 9.
